# Running Spock unit test along with TestNG in Spring boot maven based project

Tags: maven, testng, spock, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm working with IntelliJ, Spring Boot 1.3, java8 and maven.

We were using TestNG for our unit but when I started using Spock for unit test, I really liked writing test using Spock in Groovy. Here is the folder structure:

src->test->java -> All java based TestNG test lives here
src->test->groovy -> All groovy based Spock test lives here. All test have a suffix of Spec and that's how I've configured surefire plugin to look at those test.
Now when I run these individual test they work just fine. But when I run maven lifecycle command like `mvn test` or `mvn clean install`, Spock test does not run even though I have enabled maven compiler and appropriate library.

This is how my pom looks like:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.surefire}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- enables mocking of classes without default
        constructor (together with CGLIB) -->
        <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
        <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I think I'm missing something in plugin which would let maven run Spock test along with TestNG during maven lifecycle command. I think I'm missing trivial thing here. Can can someone give me some pointers here on what should I add in pom or if someone has a sample skeleton project in github which I can look at. Thanks.

Comment: What is you use `**/*Spec.java` like in the sample: https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working. Here is my updated pom.

I had two problems:

-One to run TestNG and Groovy test as a part of maven test lifecycle. This was made possible by adding dependency in surefire plugin. See below pom.

-After fixing that I had a problem another problem with Intellij where it was complaining about class already exists for my groovy based test. This was due to generated stubs in target folder. For this I had to provide configuration to override those directories as suggested by below link.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!--<This setting is for intellij bug. This override default location of groovy stubs. for more info
                check this : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153779>-->
                <stubsOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-groovy-stubs</stubsOutputDirectory>
                <testStubsOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-groovy-test-stubs</testStubsOutputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.surefire}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Spec*.groovy</include>
                    <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>junit</name>
                        <value>false</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
            </configuration>
            <!--Below dependency let's surefire play nice with groovy test and testng tests-->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.surefire}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.surefire}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I hope this helps other folks who are trying to run TestNG and Spock test together.